# curl_multi PHP: How to get resource id's of all active easy handles in a master handle

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, curl-multi

```
        $master = curl_multi_init();
        curl_multi_add_handle($master, $somehandle);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($master, $someotherhandle);
        curl_multi_exec($master, $running)
```

I know curl_multi_exec($master, $running). $running == the number of active easy handles (or uncompleted easy handles) in the master handle. Now I want to know if it's possible to get all resource id's of the active easy handles in a master handle ($master) any time, and how can I do it in PHP.
I know the following way to keep track of all completed handles and get the remaining hence the active ones,

```
$completed = curl_multi_info_read($master);
keep_track_of(completed);
```

However, I wonder if there's a more economical way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [curl_multi_info_read()](http://php.net/curl_multi_info_read).

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure what else you are asking then :)

Answer (score 0):

I think he is asking for $somehandle id